# Error while setting up pouchdb-authentication (ionic)

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I am new to angular and ionic. I was trying to setup pouchdb-authentication and got this error. I must have made some mistake somewhere but i could not fiqure it out. Please help. Before posting i searched the issue for 2 days but did not find the solution.

in app.js:

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('testLogin');
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/testLogin', {skipSetup: true});
```

and in my service:

```
remoteDB.signup(userName, password, {
              metadata : {
                email : email
              }
            }, function (err, response) {
                if(err){
                    console.log("failure signup");
                } else{
                    console.log("success signup");
                }
            });


TypeError: remoteDB.signup is not a function
    at Object.self.signup (/localhost:8100/js/services/authentication.js:40:13)
    at Scope.$scope.signup (/localhost:8100/js/controllers/authentication.js:41:16)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (/localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26457:15), <anonymous>:4:320)
    at callback (/localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:36610:17)
    at Scope.$eval (/localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the plugin is not actually installed. If you are using `<script>` tags, then you just need to make sure that the authentication script is declared after the PouchDB script. Otherwise you need to do `PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'))`.

Comment: Mistake was Authentication script declared before PuchDB script. Thanks a lot.